# Extends basic auth laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Can i expand the login function in Laravel version 5 and higher without overwriting the standard one. I want to expand the functionality without getting into the vendor folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRGJq.png)

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/'; // home initialement
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/login'; // Added

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //
}

protected function login(array $data)
{
    // my changes here...
}
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can write your own AuthController. Just make sure you manually point the routes to that controller instead of using `Auth::routes`

Comment: Yes you can but what is your exact question?  [Please read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)